# "raise e Execute Error" in the Python ArcPy module when looping

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, arcpy

The `Resample_management` function is part of the ArcPy module, a module that can only be installed along with the ArcGIS software.
It's default form is:

```
arcpy.Resample_management("D:\InputFile", "D:\OutputFile.tif", "1000 1000", "BILINEAR")
```

That way it works. But when I put it inside a loop, I get an error.

```
Input=glob.glob("D:\Freelancer\oDesk\Create-ArcPy-Scripts\TestFiles\*tif")
#Glob makes an array with all the TIF files inside a folder.
for i in Input:
    arcpy.Resample_management(i, "D:\OutputFolder\%s_1000.tif" % i, "1000 1000", "BILINEAR")


Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 12407, in Resample     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (Resample).
```

If I look up for ERROR 999999, it says "this is an error without an ID". 
Is there a problem with my loop or is it clearly a problem of the ArcPy module?

Answer (score 1):

could this be of help?

```
for i, filename in enumerate(sorted(list(Input))):
    arcpy.Resample_management(filename, "D:\OutputFolder\%s_1000.tif" % i, "1000 1000", "BILINEAR")
```

I can not try it out but I hope, it helps.

Comment: I could not try the Resample_management process itself but when I try "print i" below, it gives me a list from 0 to 5.